# How to change the css of a div using the click function on jQuery, but however twice instead of once?

Tags: jquery, css, onclick

This is the code I am using:

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(
function(){
    $("#button").click(function () {
        $('.text').css('max-width', '800px');
        $('.moretext').css('max-width', '800px');
    }); 

});
```

I am currently using the code above to edit the style of text. When the user clicks the button, the max-width of the two divs (text and moretext) change to 800px. This is working perfectly however, how do I make it so that when the user clicks the button the max-width changes to 800px, then when he clicks again, it changes to 900px, and on the third click, 1000px, and on the fourth click, back to 800px?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function getWidth(width) {
    if (!width || width >= 1000) {
      return 800;
    }

    return width + 100; 
  }

  $("#button").click(function () {
    var textMaxWidth     = parseInt($('.text').css('max-width'));
    var moreTextMaxWidth = parseInt($('.moretext').css('max-width'));

    $('.text').css('max-width', getWidth(textMaxWidth) + 'px');
    $('.moretext').css('max-width', getWidth(moreTextMaxWidth) + 'px');
  }); 

});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/fobayo/1/edit?js,output

Answer (score 0):

Just maintain a counter and then update it

```
var px = 800;
$("#button").click(function () {
    $('.text, .moretext').css('max-width', 
    px+= 100, px == 1100 ? (px = 800, '800px') : px + 'px');
});
```

The above uses a comma operator and ternary operators to do the work.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py as I see in this code there is error http://jsbin.com/fobayo/2/edit

Comment: @Alexander now it's not there. Some grouping problem now solved out

Answer (score 0):

If you're only looping through 4 options, perhaps you could use an if statement and count like this:

```
var count = 0;

$("#button").click(function () {
    if ( count == 0 ) {
        $('.text').css('max-width', '800px');
        count += 1;
    } else if ( count == 1 ) {
        $('.text').css('max-width', '900px');
        count += 1;
    } else if ( count == 2 ) {
        $('.text').css('max-width', '1000px');
        count += 1;
    } else if ( count == 3 ) {
        $('.text').css('max-width', '700px');
        count = 0;
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/0zx6y7xt/